# HP iLO4 Remote Console Java Applet display

Tags: remote, ilo

We have an HP Proliant DL360 G8 server, with iLO4 installed. I normally uses Firefox to access the iLO web interfacefrom an Ubuntu server.  The Ubuntu server hopped through 2 subnets to get to the iLO interface.

```
ubuntu$ xhost +
ssh -X 192.168.13.1
ssh -X 172.16.1.1
export MOZ_FORCE_DISABLE_E10S=1
firefox -no-remote
```

Then https://... to logon to the iLO interface.  However, when trying to run Remote Console using Java Applet, the normal Ice tea applet window is not showing anything, and there're no remote window popping up.  Is that because of export DISPLAY does not apply to JAVA applets?  Is there something I can do to fix this?
[image]

Comment: I'll be so glad when everyone has IPv6 and we no longer need to use bastion hosts, especially insanity like this. Anyway, I found recent versions of icedtea-web on Java 11 stopped working with older servers and had to find a machine with Java 8. Which is a whole separate insanity, but not as easily fixed as deploying IPv6...

Comment: Btw, if does not seem to be the java version that causes the issue.  I was able to run firefox and the Java applet on another linux box (Centos 7) with very similar Java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java applets support has been removed from both web browsers and Java itself. So you need a proper combination to run such an applet, for example Firefox up to 52 ESR and Java 8.

Alternatively, you might have success launching a java applet using `javaws` instead of browser - which is available up to Java 9 I think. I use it to launch fibre switch interfaces, for example from your command line,

```sh
javaws http://fswitch.domain.local/switchexplorer_installed.html
```

This way only an older version of Java is needed, you don't have to install an older web browser also.

Comment: The normal process now is that Firefox downloads the .jnlp file and prompts to open (with IcedTea Web Start) or save it.

Comment: Since Java applet support has been removed from Java (11 upwards) there is no "normal" process to execute them. It's whatever suits better on a mix of older software. IcedTea solution is a nice way, personally i prefer `javaws` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Though I need to find out what the argument to javaws would be to test this.  Will try.